# how to use variable data from one python file in another python file (python3.7)

Tags: python-3.x

file1.py

```
token="asdsadkj"
```

now I want to use that token in a new python file

file2.py

```
access=token      #data from file1.py
print(access)
```

output:
asdsadkj

Comment: just `import file1` in `file2.py`, I believe. There might be some weird directory stuff, but it should be fairly simple...

Comment: Why would you replace a question with several answers, with a completely different question ?

Comment: @austin I rollbacked your post to the original question. Please do **not** replace an existing question with something totally different, post a **new** question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the files are in the same directory, i.e.

```
project
|-- file1.py
\-- file2.py
```

```
# file1.py
token = "asdsadkj"
```

```
# file2.py
from file1 import token

access = token
print(token)
```

Comment: Just be warned that rebinding  `token` in `file2` will not affect `file1.token` (but you shouldn't rebind nor mutate globals anyway).

Comment: OP just edited his question to be something completely different than what they originally asked -.-

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `import` statement to import it.
In python, any files with a .py extension is a Module that you can import.
You can try:

```py
from file1 import token

print(token)
```

or

```py
# Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided,
# as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace,
# confusing both readers and many automated tools. See comment below.
from file1 import *

print(token)
```

or

```py
import file1

print(file1.token)
```

For more details, you can refer to [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Also there is a [tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages) about Modules and Packages.

Comment: Please do not advise using wildcard imports (cf https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)